# Is Android activity really visual representation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Why we call android activity visual representation of android app when it also does background tasks which have nothing to do with visual representation.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of programmers consider it a bad programming style to write code for background tasks into an `Activity` class. When aiming towards a clean architecture one would ideally only find representational code in activities. Thus, updating the views that make up the activity. As your question implies, background tasks are better found in separate classes that make up the business logic layer of an Android app.